# Using a method on a custom named (IE named at runtime) property within Bucklescript

Tags: ffi, bucklescript

So, I'm trying to program an AI for the game Screeps, whose docs are found [here](https://docs.screeps.com/api).

I'm trying to write my AI in OCaml, which I'm then compiling to Javascript via **Bucklescript**, whose docs are found [here](http://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/Manual.html).

Anywho, within Screeps' API is the method `Game.spawns.SPAWN_NAME.createCreep`, in which `SPAWN_NAME` corresponds to the name of the 'spawn' object in question. It takes in a string array corresponding to the various body parts of the 'Creep' it is helping to spawn, and given a correct function call (with enough energy reserves), your Creep will spawn in game.

An example call (in JS) would be `Game.spawns['Spawn1'].createCreep(["body","move"]);`

I already have code which gives me a `string array` of all the spawns in OCaml. That code is:

```
let spawns : string array = [%bs.raw{|Object.keys(Game.spawns)|}]
let spawnsArray : string array = spawns
```

Lets say that I have one spawn called `Spawn1`, and that  I also have a string array for the body composition in OCaml:

```
let spawnName : string = "Spawn1" 
let body : string array = [|"body","move|]
```

I then iterate over each string within that array, using a for loop like the one below:

```
for i=0 to Array.length spawns - 1 do
  // I WANT TO CALL SOMETHING ANALOGOUS TO MY FUNCTION HERE
done
```

I just can't, for the life of me, figure out how to format the Bucklescript bindings so that I can dynamically call the `createCreep` function with `body : string array` and `spawnName : string`. Any help would be amazing. I know there are the `bs.get` and `bs.set` methods described briefly within the Bucklescript docs, but I don't know how to use them.

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

### EDIT:

I managed to 'work around' the issue by writing my own 'interfacing' functions in a Javascript module which I can then call via the `bs.module` Bucklescript binding.

IE I wrote a function

```
function spawnCreepHelper(spawnName, body) {
  Game.spawns[spawnName].createCreep(body);
}
```

which I'm then able to call via

```
external spawnCreepHelper : string -> string array -> unit = "" 
[@@bs.module "./supplemental", "Supplement"]
```

Seems kind of hacked together to me, so if anyone has another way of approaching it that doesn't involve rewriting their API myself, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [bs.get_index](https://github.com/glennsl/bucklescript-ffi-cheatsheet#bsget_index) attribute:

```
type spawn
type spawns
external spawns : spawns = "" [@@bs.val] [@@bs.scope "Game"]
external getSpawn : spawns -> string -> spawn = "" [@@bs.get_index]
external createCreep : spawn -> string array -> unit = "" [@@bs.send]

let _ =
  let spawn = getSpawn spawns "spawn1" in
  createCreep spawn [|"body"; "move"|]
```

compiles to

```
var spawn = Game.spawns["spawn1"];

spawn.createCreep(/* array */[
      "body",
      "move"
    ]);
```

You can then get the keys by providing your own typed external to `Object.keys`:

```
 external keys : spawns -> string array = "" [@@bs.val] [@@bs.scope "Object"]

 let _ =
   spawns |> keys
          |> Js.Array.forEach Js.log
```

which will compile to

```
Object.keys(Game.spawns).forEach((function (prim) {
        console.log(prim);
        return /* () */0;
      }));
```

Alternatively, you could type `spawns` as a `spawn Js.Dict` and use the functions already provided by BuckleScript to access and manipulate it: https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Dict.html